# ODBC Driver Manager 'invalid string or buffer length' error

Tags: java, sql, database

I am connecting a database with my application. SELECT queries works fine that means that the connection is estabilished. When ever I use `statement.execute(parameter)` method, I can get the information that is saved at server but when ever I **try to insert** new data and use `statement.executeUpdate(parameter)` method it **throws** me a list of **errors**. Well, I am **stuck** on this issue from almost 3 days but found nothing helpful relevant to my problem.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.buildTypeInfo(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at Database.Database.InitializeDatabase(Database.java:14)
    at Clients.Customer$2.actionPerformed(Customer.java:115)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Database.Database.executeQuery(Database.java:26)
    at Clients.Customer.saveData(Customer.java:141)
    at Clients.Customer$2.actionPerformed(Customer.java:116)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

To be very particular, I can see that my issue is somewhere here or may be not. But I can't figure out why it is giving `NullPointerException`.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Database.Database.executeQuery(Database.java:26)
    at Clients.Customer.saveData(Customer.java:141)
```

This is my code from where I am trying to execute query

```
public void saveData(){
             if(!repOK()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "One or more mendetory fields are empty","Error",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
             }
             else{
                 database.executeQuery("INSERT INTO CustomerList(customerCode,customerName,resourcePerson,balance,mobile,landline) VALUES('"+customerCodeF.getText()+"','"+customerNameF.getText()+"','"+resourcePersonF.getText()+"','"+balanceF.getText()+"','"+mobileF.getText()+"','"+landLineF.getText()+"')");        
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Saved");
                 createCustomertable();
                 resetForm();
             }
    }
```

**Note:** This method is called in actionListener of save button.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                database.InitializeDatabase("Rimco");
                saveData();
                database.closeDatabase();
            }
```

Below is a snippet from my Database class that is to execute the query.

```
public void executeQuery(String query){
        try {
            //statement.executeUpdate(query);
            PreparedStatement p= connection.prepareStatement(query);
            p.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
```

First I tried to use `executeUpdate(query);` to do the job but same error showed up. Then I switched over to `PreparedStatment` but nothing happened and the same error remains.

Any idea would be of great help. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this, but last time I had an issue with an NPE for the AWT-EventQueue-0 thread, it was because I needed to wrap it in

`SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable runnable);`

Comment: @CoderMusgrove Ok, then I must try it too. Where exactly should I use it? Does this have anything to do with String or buffer length?

Comment: The NPE is a result from calling something from a thread that should be from the `AWT-EventQueue-0` thread such as revalidation of a JFrame, which I don't know how it's currently fitting into your database connection. Although, if you would like to see an awesome example on database connections that works amazingly, you could view [this](https://github.com/Huskehhh/MySQL).

Comment: @CoderMusgrove Actually I am working with a team. We all are using the same code but the problem is only at my system. May be it has something to do with buffer length. but I don't know what exactly it is.

Comment: @CoderMusgrove I tried it using mysql driver as you advised but still same problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that one of your references to a text field is null, so that when you do
`base.executeQuery("INSERT INTO CustomerList(customerCode,customerName,resourcePerson,balance,mobile,landline) VALUES('"+customerCodeF.getText()+"','"+customerNameF.getText()+"','"+resourcePersonF.getText()+"','"+balanceF.getText()+"','"+mobileF.getText()+"','"+landLineF.getText()+".....`

you're probably throwing an NPE by calling getText() on a null value that you think is a reference to  a text field.

You'll probably find it helpful to step through the code in a debugger to find this.

Oh, and you really shouldn't concatenate raw user-supplied text input into your sql statement - bind parameters to a prepared statement instead. Do a search for "SQL Injection" or "Little Bobby Tables" to find out why...

Comment: No, I have counter checked all the fields by printing the output in the console. They works perfectly fine.